# How do I reuse paths in warp?

Tags: rust, rust-warp

I'd like to have a hierarchical route structure with Rust warp like this:

```
/  
/api
/api/public
/api/public/articles
/api/admin
/api/admin/articles
```

I'd like to define my route scopes like in the following code, which is – of course – ***not*** working:

```
// *** Again: this code does NOT work.
// *** I've put it here simply for demonstration purposes

pub fn get_routes() -> impl Filter<Extract = impl warp::Reply, Error = warp::Rejection> + Clone {
   
    let articles = warp::path("articles")
        .map(|| "articles index");
    let public = warp::path("public")
        .and(warp::path::end())
        .map(|| "public index")
        .or(articles);
    let admin = warp::path("admin")
        .and(warp::path::end())
        .map(|| "admin index")
        .or(articles);
    let api = warp::path("api")
        .and(warp::path::end())
        .map(|| "api index")
        .or(admin);
    let root_index = warp::path::end()
        .map(|| "root index")
        .or(api);

    root_index

}
```

Is there any way I can achieve **piggybacking** routes i.e. scopes with rust warp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming I'm interpreting it correctly, you want to reuse paths, such that if `"api"` were to be changed, you'd only have to do so in one place.

If so, then yes you can almost do exactly what you're picturing. You just need to assign your `warp::path("...")` to a variable, and then you can reuse it for both `map()` and `and()` like so:

```rust
use warp::path::end;

let articles = warp::path("articles")
    .and(end())
    .map(|| "articles index");

let public = warp::path("public");
let public = public
    .and(end())
    .map(|| "public index")
    .or(public.and(articles));

let admin = warp::path("admin");
let admin = admin
    .and(end())
    .map(|| "admin index")
    .or(admin.and(articles));

let api = warp::path("api");
let api = api
    .and(end())
    .map(|| "api index")
    .or(api.and(admin))
    .or(api.and(public));

let root_index = end()
    .map(|| "root index")
    .or(api);
```

Comment: You totally read my mind and I apologize for letting you guess about my intentions with this code. The more I appreciate your help. Great Job!

Comment: No need to apologize, I'm just happy I could help :)

Comment: Is there a way to do this without having the root route and in general any parent route depend on the deeper routes?